# Access an external variable (Ajax call)

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I can use the URL that was requested using Ajax request with jQuery in a another Ajax call request?

For example: this is the Ajax requested url:

> http://www.google.com?action=search

This is my first Ajax call using **button 1**:

```
function display_url1() {
jQuery.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://www.google.com?action=search',
success: function(msg) {
$('#show_results').html(msg);
}
});
}
```

With the second Ajax request **(Using button2)** I want to call this url:

> http://www.google.com?action=search&category=sport

Something like that:

```
function display_url2() {
jQuery.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'THE FIRST URL + &category=sport',
success: function(msg) {
$('#show_results').html(msg);
}
});
}
```

So with the new Ajax request I want to add **&category=sport** to the first url.
So my question is how to access an external variable created with another call

Comment: So how are you making the calls?

Comment: @epascarello See update please

Comment: well you need to somehow share the url between the calls... right now there is not relationship or way to access it...

Comment: I know. How can I do that?

Comment: Depends on the code and how you call it.

Comment: @epascarello. See my update please. The two calls are almost the same.

Comment: so pass in the url to a method and one adds the QS and one does not.

Comment: Do you have a example for me please? because I can't understand you.

Comment: How do you use the two calls? With that information, I can help you.

Comment: Thanks. You can see it in my update.

Comment: What update? Still see two function calls, do not see how `display_url1` and `display_url2` are called....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So have a variable and use it in both calls. Something like:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com?q=1";

function display_url1(){
  makeCall(url);
}

function display_url2(){
  makeCall(url + "&foo=bar");
}


function makeCall(url) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    success: function(msg) {
      $('#show_results').html(msg);
    }
  });
}
```

Edit based n comment...

```
var url;
function display_url1(){
  url = "http://www.example.com?q=1";
  makeCall(url);
}

function display_url2(){
  makeCall(url + "&foo=bar");
}


function makeCall(url) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    success: function(msg) {
      $('#show_results').html(msg);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank again. I believe you didn't understand my question. The var url is created with the first call. Let say url1. Now I want to use this var in the second call. The var url1 is actually an external var for the second call.

Comment: I was trying to get DETAILS from you .... now I get them.... So than you somehow need to store the URL somewhere that it can be accessed...

Comment: Yes. That what I need. Something like session in PHP

Comment: Thanks again. We are almost there. I apologize about not being clear from the beginning. I just updated the question. I use TWO DIFFERENT BUTTONS to request the call.

Comment: so how is it any different than what I posted? You are still calling `display_url1` and `display_url2`?

Comment: When you call display_url1 you call ALSO display_url2. I don't want that.
I want first to show the results of display_url1 then I click on the second button to show display_url2.
I really hope you can help. Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: Thank you very much epascarello:)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `$.ajax()`, you can access the URL using `this.url` inside of the `complete` callback, for example:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.google.com?action=search',
    complete : function() {
        var theURL = this.url;
        // Now perform a second one:
        $.ajax({  
            url: theURL+'&category=sport'
        });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Send request</button>
```

Comment: Thanks BenM, Ok, now how can I use theURL in the second Ajax request?

Comment: @SunZ Just access the `theURL` variable.

Comment: Thanks again BenM. I get this error (Uncaught ReferenceError: theURL is not defined(…)) because the var theURL  is outside the new Ajax call. See my update please.

Comment: Pass it through as a param to the function, then. It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/h5n46f08/

Comment: I did, but it still undefined because I have two seperated calls.
I hope you can help